# Это(,) так его и назовем(,) враждебное чувство

Tags: пунктуация

> Если мы говорим о конфликте как о типе личностных отношений, то
>   непременно мы этим имеем в виду чувство, которое скрыто за этим
>   явлением. Это (?) так его и назовем (?) враждебное чувство возникает
>   по нескольким основаниям...

Нужно ли здесь как-нибудь обособить "так его и назовем"?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы обособила с помощью скобок: это же не вводное предложение, а вставная конструкция, попутное замечание.

> Если мы говорим о конфликте как о типе личностных отношений, то
>   непременно мы  имеем в виду чувство, которое скрыто за этим явлением.
>   Это (так его и назовем) враждебное чувство возникает по нескольким
>   основаниям...

Answer (score 0):

Да, это обособляемая конструкция: *Это, так его и назовем, враждебное чувство...*

Возможно, вам стоит переформулировать предложение, так как сейчас в нем имеют место тавтология (**этим**... за **этим**) и неудачно построенное выражение *мы этим имеем в виду...*